# Page isn't redirecting properly Codeigniter error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to learn Codeigniter,I have the following code, it gives me "The page isn't redirecting properly..." error.

```
public function user_login_process() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    $classes['class'] = $this->show_classes();
    $this->load->view('header');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])) {
            $this->load->view('admin_page', $classes);
        } else {
            $this->load->view('login_form');
        }
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        );
        $result = $this->login_database->login($data);
        if ($result == TRUE) {
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $result = $this->login_database->read_user_information($username);
            if ($result != false) {
                $session_data = array(
                    'username' => $result[0]->user_name,
                    'email' => $result[0]->user_email,
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
                $this->load->view('admin_page', $classes);
            }
        } else {
            $data = array(
                'error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password'
            );
            $this->load->view('login_form', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out this line

```
$this->load->view('header');
```

The page loads properly, without the header. But whenever I try to load header it fails. The problem is not with the header I believe as it loads properly on other pages.

Some context: I am trying to make an admin panel, there is a login page and a registration page and an admin page. This code segment handles the loading of admin page after successful login. Both the login and registration page loads the header file properly.

I looked into some related questions, but could not seem to find the correct solution to this issue, since I don't know what the actual issue is.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are the chance each of your pages are redirecting to each other, causing a redirect loop?

Comment: I will try step by step: `$this->session->userdata['logged_in']` You don't need user with session set available on process form. Check that on `login_form` and if user session is set redirect him accordingly. Don't allow logged in user (I.E. user with session already set) access to login and/or register page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, redirection and view file loading is not loading. Below I have written correct code with my comments where needed.

```
if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])) {
        redirect(base_url('YOUR_AUTHORIZED_CONTROLLER_OR_FUNCTION'));
    }

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    $classes['class'] = $this->show_classes();

    $this->load->view('header');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        // $this->session->userdata['logged_in'] this should not be used here. Instead you should validate your controller or methods for authorized area for logged in users
        $this->load->view('login_form');
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        );
        $result = $this->login_database->login($data);
        if ($result == TRUE) {
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $result = $this->login_database->read_user_information($username);
            if ($result != false) {
                $session_data = array(
                    'username' => $result[0]->user_name,
                    'email' => $result[0]->user_email,
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);

                // Commenting below line as you should redirect to your default authorised URL  
                //$this->load->view('admin_page', $classes);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Great! You have successfully logged in.');
                redirect(base_url('YOUR_AUTHORIZED_DEFAULT_CONTROLLER_OR_FUNCTION'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username or Password');

            // Redirect to login method and controller
            redirect(base_url('LOGIN_ACTION'));
        }
    }
```

**View:**
In your view use below line to display error/success messages. It would be better to create new view file for displaying all messages in it and load this view just after header view loaded:

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
```

Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: Thank You, this solved my problem, I will now try to understand the concept behind this properly. Thank you everyone else who took the trouble of commenting.

Comment: Your question should be marked as answered  if you got your answer 